# Making more complicated shapes

Tags: wireframe

Looking for a good way to make composite shapes.  Say we have a classic tombstone. It's a half-circle on top and a rectangle on the bottom.  I have tried doing this by either just burying a disk into a rectangle, or by cutting a disk in half then joining it to a rectangle. It stays 2 different parts, and if I join them together it still kinda sucks.

When I tried to fix the mesh manually it became abundantly clear that there had to be a better way.

Here's the sort of thing I end up with:

[image: glorious, glorious wireframe]

[image: You can see the shenanigans]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to make a shape like that, but here's how I would do it.

I would start with a Cylinder with an even number of sides (I used 12). After adding the cylinder, rotate it on the Z-Axis so that the "flat" sides are square with the axis lines (for 12 sides, 15 degrees rotates it perfectly).

[image: Cyl1]

Rotate it again on the X or Y Axis, so it's "on its side", then scale along whatever axis to make it more like a coin (like in your image).

[image: Cyl2]

Delete the large faces, then make a loop cut around the middle of the side faces. Select all the bottom faces and delete them.

[image: Cyl3]

Select the 2 bottom edges and extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) "downward" along the Z-Axis:

[image: Cyl4]

Press <kbd>F</kbd> to connect the 2 edges. Then, select the side "edge ring" with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> and select *Face > Grid Fill* from the menu at the top.

[image: Cyl5]

Do this on both sides. End result looks like this:

[image: Cyl6]

To make it more like a smooth "tombstone", add a bevel modifier and a subdivision surface modifier (in that order). Right click to shade smooth:

[image: Cyl7]